# Which is better way to write an if condition in smarty?

Tags: if-statement, smarty

Which is the better way to write an if condition in Smarty?

### A

```
{if $searchCount > 0}
```

### B

```
{if $searchCount}
```

### C

```
{if $searchCount == 0}
```

### D

```
{if !$searchCount}
```

Comment: They are translated to equivalent PHP code that uses the same operators. Use the one that fits your needs.

Comment: I don't personally know PHP, but it might not make a difference. I know in Java for example, if and switch statements are essentially compiled down to the same bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

**Example A:**

- Use this if you want to check if your `$searchCount` is greater than `0`.

**Example B:**

- Use this to check if your `$searchCount` is `true`. It's true if it's filled. No matter whats inside.

**Example C:**

- This will check if `$searchCount` is equal to `0`.

**Example D:**

- Thats the opposite of Example B. There you check if `$searchCount` is `false`. It's `false` if its not filled or it's the `bool false`.

I hope this helps you to understand the operators.

---

See the [PHP-Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) or [W3-Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp) for more informations.